arch linux headphone jack audio works for youtube on firefox, but not other players on firefox
I've recently set up arch on a new Lenovo thinkpad T14 gen 5. After reading a bit on the arch wiki page for lenovo laptops from my soundcard not being recognized (alsamixer not running, and aplay -l not showing anything) i got audio working on the headphone jack by installing sof-firmware and rebooting. However, it works via speaker-test and via youtube player (on firefox) but not in other tabs of the same firefox process! As a specific example, the audio in the embedded video player for this emacs conf talk doesnt work, and neither does audio on toobnix
What could explain this difference? Trying to understand what is likely the cause so i can try to troubleshoot and fix it...has anyone experienced similar?

Do you have either pipewire or pulseaudio installed and running? Does completely closing Firefox, then opening e.g. toobnix as the first tab, make it work for that particular tab?

If you start from a fresh reboot, open a single firefox window and visit that emacs conf site, does it work then? I am trying to see if the problem could be that you try youtube first, and that locks the sound card, blocking others from using it.

wow @terdon / grawity that seems to be it. When I opened the toobnix site first it got audio, then i opened a second tab with youtube and now youtube has no audio...when i close toobnix the youtube tab doesnt get audio until i refresh it and then it starts getting audio! Wonder what's going on...(first time encountering this)
